# ContentExtensionsDomain error 1

Tags: ios, safari-extension

I am trying to use "reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier" function of SFContentBlockerManager as follows:

```
[SFContentBlockerManager reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier:@"appid.extensionid"
                        completionHandler: ^ (NSError *error) {
    NSLog("%@", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

However, it only returns error message that said as follows:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (ContentExtensionsDomain error 1.)
```

I set both APP IDs (appid and appid.appextensionid) in "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" in developer.apple.com. Also, I made two "target"s for each -- ios app and ios app extension. I also checked open source implementations in Github which are roughly the same as mine, and App Extension manual several times, but it seems hard to find the relevant page for this problem. The most critical problem is: I couldn't find any offcial documents describing this message.

I'd appreciate if you let me know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the safari services generated swift interface, I could find the following enum for error codes:

```
public enum SFContentBlockerErrorCode : Int {
    case NoExtensionFound
    case NoAttachmentFound
    case LoadingInterrupted
}
```

So in your case it's probably the `NoAttachmentFound` error. Which can be caused by failure to initialise an item provider with given data from a json file.